# Idea needed to design spike detection

Tags: detector, spike

In our electrical workshop, they gave us to design a spike detection telling that later on we will be given a eeg signal as input to our circuit, so we had basic idea that first need to pass it through high pass filter and then amplify it but now we are stuck are in what to do next , its like we have to make a circuit and ltspice simulation for action potential detector , varying the threshold values

Comment: Start by looking up in the literature how the action potentials look. Then read up on EEG signal processing, especially older texts where analogue methods are discussed.

Comment: did that all but any idea to detect the spike without using signal processing techniques in particular

Comment: Define the spike in terms of pulse shape, pulse amplitude and duration. Define also what you don't want the detector to detect i.e. what your regular power supply ripples and transients look like.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the sparks produce RF pulses with a frequency around 100MHz, so to detect them, a Marconian antenna connected to an LC circuit tuned to this frequency and a detector should be sufficient.